How to increase vscode scrollbar?
As you can see in the image, they reduced the size of the scroll, it was very useful with the size it was, is there any way to increase it?
[https://i.sstatic.net/KnrFZYJG.png]
Edit
My mistake, it was the Minimap and not the scroll bar, I don´t know why but after update it´s hide
[https://i.sstatic.net/fRZGYH6t.png]

Modify Scrollbar Size in settings.json
"editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize": 14,
"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 14,


My mistake, it was the Minimap and not the scroll bar, I just had to active this in setting https://i.sstatic.net/fRZGYH6t.png
